# Can't get the information to show from a multi dimentional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Hey right ive made a multi-dimentional array for my uni work porb is it isnt working, ive copyied the right words well not copyed but followed the same way as i did it last time and nothing works  if anyone can tell me what part of my code is wrong then please

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

public class CMS_Program
{

public static void main(String args[])
   {

```
  String Profiles[][] = new String[9][7];








  Profiles[0][0] = "Frank Barnes";
  Profiles[0][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[0][2] = "Reykjavik";
  Profiles[0][3] = "swim Time 15:49";
  Profiles[0][4] = "Cycle Time 20:30";
  Profiles[0][5] = "Running Time 45:50";
  Profiles[0][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[1][0] = "Amy Chadwick";
  Profiles[1][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[1][2] = "Reykjavik";
  Profiles[1][3] = "swim Time 14:30";
  Profiles[1][4] = "Cycle Time 19:59";
  Profiles[1][5] = "Running Time 36:30";
  Profiles[1][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[2][0] = "Rene Thatcher";
  Profiles[2][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[2][2] = "Reykjavik";
  Profiles[2][3] = "swim Time 12:21";
  Profiles[2][4] = "Cycle Time 22:30";
  Profiles[2][5] = "Running Time 45:50";
  Profiles[2][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[3][0] = "Archie McPhadden";
  Profiles[3][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[3][2] = "Reykjavik";
  Profiles[3][3] = "swim Time 13:30";
  Profiles[3][4] = "Cycle Time 21:20";
  Profiles[3][5] = "Running Time 38:57";
  Profiles[3][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[4][0] = "Ellen Palmer";
  Profiles[4][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[4][2] = "Reykjavik";
  Profiles[4][3] = "swim Time 16:58";
  Profiles[4][4] = "Cycle Time 24:45";
  Profiles[4][5] = "Running Time 41:19";
  Profiles[4][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[5][0] = "Gerald Field";
  Profiles[5][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[5][2] = "Reykjavik";
  Profiles[5][3] = "swim Time 21:50";
  Profiles[5][4] = "Cycle Time 25:50";
  Profiles[5][5] = "Running Time 43:20";
  Profiles[5][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[6][0] = "Fay Brier";
  Profiles[6][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[6][2] = "Reykjavik";
  Profiles[6][3] = "swim Time 14:20";
  Profiles[6][4] = "Cycle Time 22:53";
  Profiles[6][5] = "Running Time 47:23";
  Profiles[6][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[7][0] = "Richard Ranking";
  Profiles[7][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[7][2] = "Reykjavik";
  Profiles[7][3] = "swim Time 12:43";
  Profiles[7][4] = "Cycle Time 26:34";
  Profiles[7][5] = "Running Time 38:26";
  Profiles[7][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[8][0] = "Amy Chadwick";
  Profiles[8][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[8][2] = "Gibraltar";
  Profiles[8][3] = "swim Time 18:47";
  Profiles[8][4] = "Cycle Time 21:28";
  Profiles[8][5] = "Running Time 51:12";
  Profiles[8][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[9][0] = "Gerald Field";
  Profiles[9][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[9][2] = "Gibraltar";
  Profiles[9][3] = "swim Time 21:02";
  Profiles[9][4] = "Cycle Time 22:50";
  Profiles[9][5] = "Running Time 50:45";
  Profiles[9][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[10][0] = "Frank Barnes";
  Profiles[10][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[10][2] = "Gibraltar";
  Profiles[10][3] = "swim Time 19:48";
  Profiles[10][4] = "Cycle Time 26:45";
  Profiles[10][5] = "Running Time 52:34";
  Profiles[10][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[11][0] = "Richard Ranking";
  Profiles[11][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[11][2] = "Gibraltar";
  Profiles[11][3] = "swim Time 18:20";
  Profiles[11][4] = "Cycle Time 24:20";
  Profiles[11][5] = "Running Time 56:55";
  Profiles[11][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[12][0] = "Deirdre Wilder";
  Profiles[12][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[12][2] = "Gibraltar";
  Profiles[12][3] = "swim Time 22:50";
  Profiles[12][4] = "Cycle Time 27:32";
  Profiles[12][5] = "Running Time 52:23";
  Profiles[12][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[13][0] = "Rene Thatcher";
  Profiles[13][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[13][2] = "Gibraltar";
  Profiles[13][3] = "swim Time 20:07";
  Profiles[13][4] = "Cycle Time 22:45";
  Profiles[13][5] = "Running Time 56:32";
  Profiles[13][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[14][0] = "Fay Brier";
  Profiles[14][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[14][2] = "Gibraltar";
  Profiles[14][3] = "swim Time 19:42";
  Profiles[14][4] = "Cycle Time 24:09";
  Profiles[14][5] = "Running Time 54:52";
  Profiles[14][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[15][0] = "Tom March";
  Profiles[15][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[15][2] = "Gibraltar";
  Profiles[15][3] = "swim Time 18:22";
  Profiles[15][4] = "Cycle Time 23:31";
  Profiles[15][5] = "Running Time 53:12";
  Profiles[15][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[16][0] = "Rene Thatcher";
  Profiles[16][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[16][2] = "Southhampton";
  Profiles[16][3] = "Swim Time 15:52";
  Profiles[16][4] = "Cycle Time 19:50";
  Profiles[16][5] = "Running Time 34:40";
  Profiles[16][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[17][0] = "Ellen Palmer";
  Profiles[17][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[17][2] = "Southhampton";
  Profiles[17][3] = "swim Time 15:20";
  Profiles[17][4] = "Cycle Time 21:22";
  Profiles[17][5] = "Running Time 33:27";
  Profiles[17][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[18][0] = "Archie McPhadden";
  Profiles[18][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[18][2] = "Southhampton";
  Profiles[18][3] = "swim Time 13:39";
  Profiles[18][4] = "Cycle Time 18:35";
  Profiles[18][5] = "Running Time 34:21";
  Profiles[18][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[19][0] = "Fay Brier";
  Profiles[19][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[19][2] = "Southampton";
  Profiles[19][3] = "Swim Time 14:20";
  Profiles[19][4] = "Cycle Time 19:19";
  Profiles[19][5] = "Running Time 31:56";
  Profiles[19][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[20][0] = "Amy Chadwick";
  Profiles[20][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[20][2] = "Southampton";
  Profiles[20][3] = "swim Time 13:59";
  Profiles[20][4] = "Cycle Time 17:51";
  Profiles[20][5] = "Running Time 30:12";
  Profiles[20][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[21][0] = "Tom March";
  Profiles[21][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[21][2] = "southhampton";
  Profiles[21][3] = "swim Time 13:50";
  Profiles[21][4] = "Cycle Time 18:56";
  Profiles[21][5] = "Running Time 30:54";
  Profiles[21][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[22][0] = "Deirdre Wilder";
  Profiles[22][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[22][2] = "Southampton";
  Profiles[22][3] = "swim Time 15:12";
  Profiles[22][4] = "Cycle Time 21:19";
  Profiles[22][5] = "Running Time 34:53";
  Profiles[22][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[23][0] = "Gerald Field";
  Profiles[23][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[23][2] = "Southampton";
  Profiles[23][3] = "swim Time 14:54";
  Profiles[23][4] = "Cycle Time 20:55";
  Profiles[23][5] = "Running Time 35:31";
  Profiles[23][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[24][0] = "Frank Barnes";
  Profiles[24][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[24][2] = "Bourges";
  Profiles[24][3] = "Swim Time 17:40";
  Profiles[24][4] = "Cycle Time 21:20";
  Profiles[24][5] = "Running Time 51:20";
  Profiles[24][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[25][0] = "Richard Ranking";
  Profiles[25][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[25][2] = "Bourges";
  Profiles[25][3] = "Swim Time 13:01";
  Profiles[25][4] = "Cycle Time 20:34";
  Profiles[25][5] = "Running Time 54:47";
  Profiles[25][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[26][0] = "Archie McPhadden";
  Profiles[26][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[26][2] = "Bourges";
  Profiles[26][3] = "Swim Time 12:25";
  Profiles[26][4] = "Cycle Time 20:02";
  Profiles[26][5] = "Running Time 49:34";
  Profiles[26][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[27][0] = "Amy Chadwick";
  Profiles[27][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[27][2] = "Bourges";
  Profiles[27][3] = "Swim Time 12:21";
  Profiles[27][4] = "Cycle Time 19:59";
  Profiles[27][5] = "Running Time 48:32";
  Profiles[27][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[28][0] = "Tom March";
  Profiles[28][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[28][2] = "Bourges";
  Profiles[28][3] = "Swim Time 14:50";
  Profiles[28][4] = "Cycle Time 20:00";
  Profiles[28][5] = "Running Time 48:27";
  Profiles[28][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[29][0] = "Ellen Palmer";
  Profiles[29][1] = "Female";
  Profiles[29][2] = "Bourges";
  Profiles[29][3] = "Swim Time 13:56";
  Profiles[29][4] = "Cycle Time 21:30";
  Profiles[29][5] = "Running Time 51:23";
  Profiles[29][6] = "Over 18";

  Profiles[30][0] = "Rene Thatcher";
  Profiles[30][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[30][2] = "Bourges";
  Profiles[30][3] = "Swim Time 14:23";
  Profiles[30][4] = "Cycle Time 21:02";
  Profiles[30][5] = "Running Time 52:44";
  Profiles[30][6] = "Under 18";

  Profiles[31][0] = "Gerald Field";
  Profiles[31][1] = "Male";
  Profiles[31][2] = "Bourges";
  Profiles[31][3] = "Swim Time 14:01";
  Profiles[31][4] = "Cycle Time 26:59";
  Profiles[31][5] = "Running Time 50:05";
  Profiles[31][6] = "Under 18";




  for (int row = 0; row < Profiles.length; row++)
  {
     System.out.println("here ");
     for (int column = 0; column < 1; column++)
     {
        System.out.println('\t' + Profiles[row][column] + '\t');
     }
  }
```

}
}

Comment: in future, try and describe somewhat more verbosely what you're trying to do, what precisely isn't working, and what you've tried to do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign like 32 index values in this array, although you defined its size as `String[9][7]`

Try this declaration instead:

`String Profiles[][] = new String[32][7];`

Comment: Ive changed it and it just keeps saying build successful 0 time and thats it nothing else :S

Comment: @Josh, again, i cannot know what you're doing on your computer, so if you want help, you need to explain. Was the original problem before the change an ArrayOutOfBounds exception? it was, although i had to think about that and you could have saved me some time by telling me. What is "it" that keeps saying build successful? are you in an IDE, are you on the command line? have you tried printing other variables? help me help you mate.

Comment: the outbook box in netbeans just says "run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)" that all it says, there isnt a error on the code itself theres no red lines nothing looks wrong but something appears to cause a problem, all i want it to do is print out on the outbox on netbeans.

Comment: what's an outbook box? in any case, have you tried running your code now that youve built/compiled it?

Comment: sorry i meant output box, it displays whats going on in the program when u do a system.out.println, Yes and nothing happens.

Comment: dont know what more to tell you, i run the code above with the change and it prints all the details. check that you havent changed anything in the print loop

Comment: oh okies then, nd no i havent changed out my fiancee who did the same project as me doesnt know whats wrong either sigh thanks anyway man im going to have to get the tutor to have a look at it *sigh* hes going to laugh :P